# Dynamic Src in HTML in a Script Tag

Tags: html

I have a script:

```
<script src="http://192.168.0.187:3004/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

The IP Address is subject to change which I have no control of, so I'm thinking of having the IP dynamic.

Like this:

```
<script src="http://" + location.host + "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But of course this doesn't work.

I did however came across this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="">
    document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].src += "http://" + location.host + "/socket.io/socket.io.js";
</script>
```

But still doesn't work. This is not my strongest point so, any clue?

**EDIT:**

Here is the sample of my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SAMPLE</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script id="script" src=""></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("script").src = "http://" + location.host + "/socket.io/socket.io.js";
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <table id="table" border=1>
      <thead>
        <th><center>Sample</center></th>
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="online"></tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
      var ipServer = location.host;
      var socket = io.connect('ws://' + ipServer);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should see if you could disable DHCP from the target IP and then make it static.

Comment: @SimonJensen - So that the IP would no longer change? I want to solve this thinking that the IP is subject to change. Actually, that's the case as this is the client's limitation which I have to adjust to, sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is call dynamically loading javascript:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute( 'src', 'socket.io.js');
document.head.appendChild(script);
//script that use socket.io
```

But there's another problem that you don't know when the script is fully loaded. If you call a function is defined in external script before it's loaded, it's error!

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
    //script that use socket.io
};
script.setAttribute( 'src', 'socket.io.js');
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

And we can make a utility function:

```
function loadScript(scriptPath, callback) {
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', scriptPath);
    script.onload = callback();
    document.head.appendChild(s);
};

loadScript('socket.io.js', function() {
    //script that use socket.io
});
```

OR you can use jQuery $.getScript():

```
$.getScript('socket.io.js', function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    //script that use socket.io
});
```

For more information: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

PS: with your code, it will be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>SAMPLE</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script id="script" src=""></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript">-->
            <!--document.getElementById("script").src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js";-->
        <!--</script>-->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">-->
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <table id="table" border=1>
        <thead>
        <th><center>Sample</center></th>
        <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="online"></tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.onload = function () {
            var ipServer = location.host;
            var socket = io.connect('ws://' + ipServer);
        };
        script.setAttribute( 'src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js');
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answering! I wanna do something simple similar to what @Obsidian Age answered, however I still encountered an issue 'io is not defined'. I've added my HTML for reference. Also, instead of using ByTagName, i used ID to have the changes have an effect only on one specific script tag. Still won't work though. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah I did however it resulted into an error, which I assumed I was doing it wrong. That's why I wanna do something a little too simple. What I did was based on the html (edit) in my question, I added the data from the script (the one with two declaration of 'var') inside your 2nd code of block specifically inside where you commented '//script that use socket.io'.

Comment: @DayIsGreen I am afraid of that when you edit the src of html, it does not load the script, in my solution, the script will be load when call appendChild()

Comment: I'm not much of a front end programmer but, I have the same thoughts. that said, when i tried adjusting my codes, i get the message 'Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.0.187:3004/socket.io.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.'; I am totally clueless if i'm doing this right, but what i did was, inside the script tags, i added your 2nd block, where in inside the comment section, i added my supposed codes to which in my understanding from your previous comment, will be called as it is now called 'script'.

Comment: @DayIsGreen I have updated my answer from you code, pls check it

Comment: Holy ****, nevermind! It worked! Your code finally worked! I just had to edit a small code. Thanks! upvoting this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) to load the script.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://' + location.host + '/socket.io/socket.io.js"><\/script>';
    document.write(script);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea; the problem is that you can't combine an external script (using `src`) with an inline one.

You simply need two different scripts for this, making sure the inline one comes after the reference to an external script:

```html
<script src=""></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].src = "http://" + location.host + "/socket.io/socket.io.js";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I adjusted my codes and it didn't work. So instead of using ByTagName, i used ID but still failed. I've posted the sample of my html. By pressing F12, console says I'm having issue with the line: var socket = io.connect('ws://' + ipServer); as io was not declared or something. It seems my changes didn't work.

Comment: Also, I've added the my html as sample for reference. I've changed the tag from name to ID as i think it may cause changes in all script tags, so i used ID instead to have the changes focused on one specific script tag