# How to execute dynamic string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, tags

I have dynamic string javascript tags to execute in head of html.

Tags as follow and this tags is dynamic comes from server as a string and I want to execute this javascript into head of html. How can I best achieve this?

```
<script async src="/content/js/file1.js"></script>
<script async src="/content/js/file1.js"></script>
<script> alert('Execute'); </script>
```

Comment: What is the actual issue? Does the script tage arrive as a string? Why?

Comment: The actual issue is that, i create some external javascript file and i want to execute this script into the head of my project.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea; the problem is that you can't combine an external script (using src) with an inline one.

You simply need two different scripts for this, making sure the inline one comes after the reference to an external script:

```
<script src=""></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].src = "http://" + location.host + "/content/js/file1.js";
</script>
```

Comment: More Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196087/dynamic-src-in-html-in-a-script-tag